# what is the minimum data size used in the database level Projects?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, relational-database

I have been called for telephonic round and asked a question like how much data size have been used in the project . I think this question is about size of the project . They are expecting in Some GB . :)

Comment: Who were the person(s) who asked you this question, and are you sure they even understand database very well?

Comment: Recruiter , ya They have a knowledge about database .

Comment: Please help me regarding above my concerns

Comment: `I didn't get the exact meaning of question` You should have asked for more clarifications,as of now this is unclear

Comment: ya ok ..Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datasize is the amount of data size used in the project.
You can justify your answer by telling number of tables , rows of data used etc.
or like

12gb to 15gb is the range where developer used in the project. It may vary but we can put our answer in front of Interviewer .

This range is provided by DBA team .

Or we talk technical

We can number of tables, data used in the tables we can elaborate and explain

Answer (score 1):

Is it a project with some statistical analysis or something  heavily dependent on probability? Then **SAMPLE SIZE** is often (wrongly) worded as DATA SIZE when you speak about data gathering and DB to support that.

In simple terms -  how much data have you used to notice / link / prove some hypothesis.

It's more suited for math section of SE then. But if you need to take a quick look into more explanation then you could at least skip-read this:

[sample size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination)

If it's not this, then you should encourage the person to explain itself, and tell her it's not the standard term when speaking with DB admins. Maybe management uses it for something completely different. But IMHO it's the interviewer job to know the communication with his/her target audience, especially when being told something is not understood.

Personally, if someone pointed out something like this immediately to me during interview I would take it a s a proof he knows his domain well and is proactive in asking what he/she doesn't understand, but might be that some managers full of ego would take it as an insult.

Comment: ya ok Thank you . Danthe